# How to get temperory location of file in tinymce ajax upload image

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to receive temporary image path in controller uploaded through tinymce post body. I get 500 error

My js is [this](https://controlc.com/355dbadb)

Route:
`Route::post('/postAcceptor', 'postAcceptorController@index');`

My controller

```
public function index($data) {
    $file = request()->file('file');
    $file_path = $file->getPathName();

    return json_encode(['location' => $file_path]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Request $request` like :

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('file'); 
    $file_path = $file->getPathName();
    
    return json_encode(['location' => $file_path]);
}
```

You can try `dd( $request->all() )` to check if you're receiving the file from the client side.

Comment: Thanks, I get the path now. But the problem is I want to give it to imgur api to upload and get the url. So I have [this](https://controlc.com/1c681be3). Now I get 500 error.

Comment: Try to use this package instead, https://packages.yish.dev/packages/laravel-imgur.html#requirement

Comment: I know that package, but I was trying to make it clean as possible

Comment: Ok please close this question because seems like it's resolved, and add a new one with the specific Imgur issue, so you can get more help.